# Adding common footer to two listviews

Tags: android

I have two list views in one linear layout. Both list views are arranged in such a way that the screen should be divided in to half vertically. Here are my list views:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llListviewWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvProductListLeft"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/product_list_divider_height"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/product_list_padding_sides"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvProductListRight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/product_list_divider_height"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/product_list_padding_sides"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

The issue that I am facing is that, I am unable to show a common footer area, which should indicate that more items are being loaded to both list views. I have tried addfooterview method, but it will result in two footers which will be added to both list views. What I need is to show a common footer at the end of both list views.

Comment: Why not just use a 3rd element that is either visible or not visible and not use addfooterview?

Comment: I have tried that earlier, by making the 3rd element visible when the list view reaches it's end and make it gone when it is scrolled up. But it does not give a feeling that, it's connected to list view.

Comment: @roy mathew Have you solved this common footer problem. I am also facing same issue...

Answer (score 1):

In your listview adapter `getView()` method you can try to inflate a different layout depending on the position of the listview item.

This way you can make the last cell saying that there are more things to load in your list.